# Problem defining the tiling starting point

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt

We are tiling a image datasets. However, we want to specifically define custom windows. To do this, we are using -te option during warping. The warped output is then tiled. The problem though is that after tiling and checking the BBOX of the first tile, we have noticed that the starting coordinate is shifted as illustrated below:

[image]

1. The blue grid represent the original dataset with cell size (a).
2. The black grid represent the new dataset with cell size (b).
3. The cell size of both datasets can be the same or not [(a) .eq. (b) or (a) .ne. (b)].
4. The red polygon represent the BBOX which fit to the new cell size and tile size.

We would like to start tiling exactly at the upper left corner of the red polygon. How we can force GDAL to clip the raster exactly according to our well defined BBOX?

In some cases, GDAL picks the right BBOX start point, in other cases it doesn't. Is this some how related to the difference in the input and output data resolution (cell size)?

We can't figure out why it is ignoring our definitions. Could someone help shade some light to what is happening here?